# Drivers and firmware for the LiteOn ihap-122-9 DVD drive

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, dvd, updates, firmware

I'm trying to replace the DVD drive in my old PC.  LiteOn.com is a mess and I can't find a single working driver or firmware update there, or anywhere.   Windows XP tries to use a default, generic driver dated 2001.   (About 9 years before this drive even existed.)

http://www.firmwarehq.com/download_1..._6L0H.EXE.html

This correctly finds my LiteOn ihap-122-9 DVD Drive.

It correctly finds that I'm currently using firmware 6L0F.

It correctly tries to install 6L0H.

It completes 100% but then just fails and says "contact your vendor".

Does anyone know why?

Where can I actually get drivers... and firmware updates... that actually work for the ihap-122-9?

Apparently, the newest driver *IS* the 1 made 9 years before the drive existed.  (Unbelievable.)  And the latest firmware is the 1 that is already in the drive.  (Common.)

No other drive I've had in this computer ever had a problem.  This brand new LiteOn is doing this:

- Opening MY COMPUTER now takes 60 seconds.
- MY COMPUTER marking the drive as "DVD F:" takes another 30 seconds.
- MY COMPUTER showing "Batman II" title takes another 15 seconds.
- Clicking and running the movie will take another
  30 seconds for the main-menu to appear.
- The movie starts about 20 seconds later.
- The movie runs fine for 1-2 seconds... then stops for 5
  seconds.... then starts again and
  plays for 1-2 seconds.
- Repeats for 2 hours.

(It happens with all store-bought DVDs and all home-made DVDs.)

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, the newest driver IS the 1 made 9 years before the drive existed. (Unbelievable.)

Not unbelievable at all; quite the opposite. The driver is simply a piece of software in the OS that the it uses to communicate with the drive and is based on standards that drive manufactures adhere to. Therefore, the standard one should work for pretty much all drives. *Very* rarely will you find one that is not standards compliant and requires a specialized driver; yours is not one of them.

> And the latest firmware is the 1 that is already in the drive. (Common.)

The firmware is a piece of software in the drive that it uses to communicate with its parts and to know how to handle different discs. From your description, the firmware is not the problem. If it never worked, it is defective. If it did used to work and has since stopped, did you do anything since the last time it worked (eg upgrades to hardware or software)? Had you installed any programs? Had you bumped cables or cords?

The description of the problem you gave sounds *very much* like the disc is dirty or scratched (or possibly just a bad pressing). Had you tried a different disc?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an OEM drive, then you will have to get firmware from the original vendor, such as HP, Dell etc.

I would never use a 3rd party site like that for firmware, it could damage the drive, rendering it useless.

What Make and Model of PC is it?

Comment: It's just an old PC that I built myself... many years ago.  The DVD drive died so I'm trying to replace it with a new one.

Comment: You can find official LiteOn firmware here....http://us.liteonit.com/us/index.php?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=75

Comment: Where did the drive come from?

Comment: I purchased the drive at any of 100 random online stores.  (They all say "contact liteon" for support.)

Comment: LiteOn.com gives me a file called UL02.rar that I extract to UL02.exe.  It also finds my drive, but says it's only for the ihap122-8, not the 122-9.  And they offer NO drivers at all.

Comment: Its firmware, not a driver, completely different, not all drives have firmware updates available. You might edit your original post to include exactly what you are trying to do or solve.

Comment: Sure would be nice if LiteOn just stated:  "drive 9 has NO firmware update at all"  I would stop wasting my time.

Comment: As for a driver... I will take *ANY* driver other than the generic Windows XP driver that was made 9 years before this drive even existed.  Shouldn't LiteOn.com have a "newer" driver... or "any driver" at all?  I sure can't find any at all.

Comment: There is no driver update for optical drives, the generic one works fine, like I said edit your original post to include what problems you are trying solve.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what a "driver" does for a piece of hardware.  A driver can be designed today... that will fully work for drives that won't be designed/built/exist until 2019?   Drivers designed *YEARS* before DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD-DL formats even existed... will fully work with when those formats are invited?

Comment: I thought "install latest driver" and "latest firmware" were always the good places to start when things don't work.  No?  I should instead struggle trying to get a drive to work... when it doesn't stand a chance?

Comment: "latest driver" does not apply to optical drives, never has, they have always been "generic" drivers, no need to update them, its about the only piece of removeable hardware that is this way. I would return the drive if you can, get another brand.

Comment: Fundamentally, what is going on is the methods the OS uses to talk to the drive are standardized. Therefore, as long as a drive adheres to the standard, drivers that are written to interface with hardware that follows the standard will also work. This means that even if the drivers are older than the drive, as long as the drive behaves predictably, it will work.